# Android: Volley Image loader with gallery

Tags: android, gallery, android-volley, image-loading

I'm trying to implement a Gallery element using Volley's ImageLoader. On the following request I receive a list with some URLs which it will be shown on the Gallery. My problem is that the Gallery isn't displaying anything.

```
RestApiAdapter.getImages("Food", new RestApiAdapter.RestApiCallBack<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void execute(List<String> object) {
        GaleriaAdapter gAdapter = new GaleriaAdapter(foodFragmentView.getContext());
        gAdapter.setImages(object);

        ((Gallery) foodFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.gallery)).setAdapter(gAdapter);
    }
});
```

now the adapter

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
...
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String url = (String) getItem(position);
    ImageLoader imgLoader = VolleyRequest.getInstance(null).getImageLoader();

    NetworkImageView imgView = new NetworkImageView(context);
    imgView.setImageUrl(url, imgLoader);

    return imgView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out the problem after a while. Basically it was missing the request itself i assume

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String url = (String) getItem(position);
    NetworkImageView imgView = new NetworkImageView(context);
    ImageLoader imgLoader = VolleyRequest.getInstance(null).getImageLoader();

    // This line of code
    imgLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imgView, LOADING_IMG, ERROR_IMG));

    imgView.setImageUrl(url, imgLoader);
    return imgView;
}
```

Source: http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-volley-imageloader-networkimageview-example/

Answer (score 0):

Are you notifyDataSetChange() after adding adapter to Grid?

```
gAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It didn't worked here but i found the answer but thank you anyway